# Como agregar filas a tabla en Android

Tags: android

Buenos días chicos, soy nuevo en Android, he consultado en muchos sitios y quisiera saber la manera de agregar filas o registros a una tabla en Android, agradezco la colaboración.

Código del Layout:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/Cabecera"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ColumnaCedula"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="Cédula"
            android:textColor="#005500"
            android:textSize="21dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ColumnaNombre"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="Nombre Operario"
            android:textColor="#005500"
            android:textSize="21dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ColumnaCargo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5px"
            android:text="Cargo"
            android:textColor="#005500"
            android:textSize="21dp" />
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/SeparadorCabecera"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/LineaCabecera"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2px"
            android:layout_span="6"
            android:background="#FFFFFF" >
        </FrameLayout>
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Código Java: Agrega una fila a la tabla cuando se hace click en al botón

```
public void AgregarFilaTabla(View view)
{
   TableLayout tabla = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblOperarios);

   String params[] = {"Dato 1", "Dato 2", "Dato 2"};
   TableRow row = new TableRow(params);
   tabla.addView(row);
}
```

Comment: hola deseas realizar esto con Sqlite ?

Comment: comparte el código para ver que tienes, y nosotros te decimos como agregarlo

Comment: Buenos días chicos, si, la idea es realizar un registro local (Por medio de SQLite) de cada fila que el usuario agregue al control TableLayout.

Comment: Hola @FelipeMendietaPerez, deberías editar tu pregunta y compartir el código que has hecho, para que podamos ver de forma clara y concreta que es lo que intentas hacer y poder ayudarte a encontrar una solución.

Comment: Te recomiendo que agregues lo que lleves hecho, es mas facil ayudarte de esa manera

Comment: Listo chicos, parte del código, de lo que he llegado a encontrar

Comment: Sé que hay error en la parte que instancio la variable row, porque precisamente no sé como pasarle los string que tendrán las celdas, gracias por vuestra colaboración

Comment: @FelipeMendietaPerez Necesitas el contexto para instanciar el TableRow: new TableRow(this); o new TableRow(getApplicationContext());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para instanciar el `TableRow` debes usar el contexto, y no un array:

```
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
```

y para el texto puedes agregar un `TextView`

```
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("Dato 1");
tv.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

y posteriormente agregas el elemento al `TableRow`:

```
row.addView(tv);
```

lo mismo para agregar el `TableRow` al `TableLayout`:

```
TableRow.addView(row);
```

Comment: Perfecto me funcionó  bien, muchas gracias!

Comment: Me parece que el único problema era al instanciar el TableRow() , saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ